# Django - Writing unit tests with mocks

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I started working on a Django project recently. To start off with, I read the [book on TDD with Python](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/index.html) and the official documentation (for [tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/overview/)). And a few more blogs as well.

One thing I notice is, they write tests that access the database models. Consider the following snippet from [here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch05.html#_better_unit_testing_practice_each_test_should_test_one_thing)

```
def test_home_page_can_save_a_POST_request(self):
    request = HttpRequest()
    request.method = 'POST'
    request.POST['item_text'] = 'A new list item'

    response = home_page(request)

    self.assertEqual(Item.objects.count(), 1)
    new_item = Item.objects.first()
    self.assertEqual(new_item.text, 'A new list item')
```

The test asserts whether the number of `Item` objects is 1. So the test actually adds and retrieves data from the database. Wouldn't that make the test slow?

If the tests are parallelized, this test case may fail if there is another test which adds an `Item` object, right?

How about patching methods / objects? The above snippet can be refactored like this

```
@patch('my_app.views.Item')
def test_home_page_can_save_a_POST_request(self, mock_item):
    request = HttpRequest()
    request.method = POST
    request.POST['item_text'] = 'A new list item'

    response = home_page(request)

    self.assertTrue(mock_item.objects.create.called)
```

I am new to Django and I am not familiar with the practices. The tutorials I visited wrote tests that talk to database. I would like to know, whether that is the convention for testing in Django projects. Is the second snippet (using patches and mock) perfectly fine in the Django ecosystem?

Edit: Same with Forms as well - Mocking `form.is_valid` method to return `True` or `False`, provided there are separate unit tests for Forms.

P.S. TDD with Python is an awesome book that helped me to a great extend in on-boarding. I definitely recommend that to anyone learning Django.

Comment: Tests run in their own transactions so are independent of each other as far as data that's available/expected. (Thanks for the pointer to the book -- looks great!)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test your models, you can hardly bypass the database, and yes indeed it can make the tests somewhat slower, even if using an in-memory SQLite db - which can lead to other problems FWIW since SQLite is not a transparant replacement for something like PostgreSQL.

But assuming whatever model or or other function / object / method you call in your views have their own unittest and you only want to check your views do the expected calls, mocking is viable strategy - actually probably saner than testing the results of the expected calls (which mostly turn your unittests into integration tests).

Comment: I believe the same applies to `Forms` as well. I can mock `form.is_valid` to return `True` or `False` and test my SUT. Of course, after writing unit tests for Forms.